# google compute engine connection keeps disconecting

Tags: python, ios, django, google-compute-engine

I have an instance on **google compute engine**, connecting to it by terminal: `gcutil ssh`, on it I have several **DJango servieces**. I run the server using: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. the services are being called from an **iPhone application** IOS 6.1

**the problem** I'm facing is that every few minutes (between 10- 15) I'm getting disconnected and have to reconnect and run the server again.

Why is my server being disconnected and how can I keep the it running?

Answer (score 0):

Try using supervisor.d. It sounds like for what your trying to do, supervisor can keep your process up and running. http://supervisord.org/
Here's an example conf:

```
[program:app]
process_name = app-%(process_num)s
command =python /home/ubuntu/production/current/app/src/app.py --port=%(process_num)s

# Increase numprocs to run multiple processes on different ports.
# Note that the chat demo won't actually work in that configuration
# because it assumes all listeners are in one process.
numprocs = 4
numprocs_start = 8000
```

This is for running multiple processes of the same program. Just change around the args and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

SSH normally times out after a period of inactivity, and that may be what is happening here. If so, [this article](http://ocaoimh.ie/2008/12/10/how-to-fix-ssh-timeout-problems/) might be useful to help configure SSH to send a regular message so connections are less likely to be dropped.

However, the core issue is that you'd like software you started at the terminal to keep running even when you're logged out. Consider using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to host your shell sessions. This will allow your shell software to run even when you are not connected, and for you to pick up right where you left off when you reconnect. Here is a nice [getting started post about tmux](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course).

Once you're ready for production, take a look at the [Django deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/).